# Add tags to the Stack Overflow newsletter

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, newsletter

Could someone add tags to the featured questions in the Stack Overflow newsletter? I find it annoying to have to follow each question's link to figure out which tags apply to it, though this may have been an intentional decision to increase click-through rates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Newsletters](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters) show tags now.

Examples:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=stackoverflow.com)
- [TeX - LaTeX](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=tex.stackexchange.com)
- [User Experience](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=ux.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Hi! maybe three obsolete links!